# Json data adapter

Tags: go

I want to take JSON in

```
{ name: "http://example.com", ...}
```

and map it to

```
{ url: "http://example.com", ...}
```

I want to do this mapping and be able to Marshal back to json as Url.  The struct is rather large, so is it possible to do this with one struct instead creating multiple struct types?

This is the solution I have come to so far: http://play.golang.org/p/wBPbSjkTYF

After seeing answers and how I failed to accurately describe my use case.  Updating to the actual mapping I'm trying to do:

```
{ "data": { "name": "http://example.com", "key": "value" } }
```

To:

```
{ "url": "http://example.com", { "data": "key": "value" } }
```

Comment: I took the first answer and came full circle to this solution: http://play.golang.org/p/Z_uyhvXC-4.  It makes use of `omitempty` to make the default marshaller.  Answer #1 still seems the Go way of achieve json mappings in Go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json` package doesn't have any tags that allows you to use one key name of a field on Marshal and a different on Unmarshal.

It is still possible to Marshal a struct to differently, but in order to do that you will have to implement your own Marshaller (MarshalJSON function). A working example:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Url string `json:"name"`
}

// marshalObject takes a slice of key values
// (should be correctly escaped json strings without "")
// and another slice of interface{} values and marshals
// them into a JSON object string
func marshalObject(keys []string, values []interface{}) ([]byte, error) {

    if len(keys) != len(values) {
        panic("Different length of keys and values slices")
    }

    if len(keys) == 0 {
        return []byte(`{}`), nil
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.Write([]byte(`{"`))

    for i, key := range keys {
        if i != 0 {
            b.Write([]byte(`,"`))
        }
        b.WriteString(key)
        b.Write([]byte(`":`))
        j, err := json.Marshal(values[i])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        b.Write(j)
    }

    b.Write([]byte(`}`))

    return b.Bytes(), nil
}

func (d *Data) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // Here you can add a list of keys and values.
    // Currently it is only `url` mapped to d.Url
    return marshalObject(
        []string{
            `url`,
        },
        []interface{}{
            d.Url,
        },
    )
}

func main() {
    i := []byte(`{"name":"http://example.com"}`)
    fmt.Printf("Json Input: %+s\n", i)

    var d *Data
    err := json.Unmarshal(i, &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Data: %#v\n", d)

    o, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Json Output: %+s\n", o)

}
```

**Result:**

```
Json Input: {"name":"http://example.com"}
Data: &main.Data{Url:"http://example.com"}
Json Output: {"url":"http://example.com"}
```

**Playground:**

http://play.golang.org/p/u6ExI9V95D

Comment: I think this is the best way to achieve what I'm looking for.  I wish it wasn't so daunting looking at it though.

Comment: Is it possible to use reflection to get all the field values?  It would be a pain to manually add every key in struct to the MarshalJson example.

Comment: I understand the hesitation. But it is possible to use reflection as well. You could even make your own tag (`jsonmarshal:"url"`). However, you would still need to create this MarshalJSON method. You would gain having the key names in the struct instead of in the slice. I can try to make a reflection example when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

If you unmarshal a JSON object into an `map[string]interface{}` variable, you will be given everything in the object rather than just a few fields.  It should be fairly straight forward to make the required modifications, like so:

```
func nameToUrl(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    var obj map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if name, ok := obj["name"]; ok {
        delete(obj, "name")
        obj["url"] = name
    }
    return json.Marshal(obj)
}
```

You can experiment with this here: http://play.golang.org/p/0jz_HAGg3E

Comment: I like the simplicity of  this solution, but how do you handle JSON with nested objects?  This works fine for the { key: value, key: value }, but won't work for { key: { key: value, key: value}}.  Unless I'm mistaken

Comment: What do you mean? If you follow the playground link, you'll see that it is preserving the rest of the data in the JSON, including nested objects.

Comment: For instance, if this was my input: `{"s":"foo", "b":true, "n":1, "a":[0,1], "o":{"name":"http://example.com"}}`}.  How do you handle nested mappings?

Comment: The whole JSON structure will be decoded.  You could access that embedded field using a type assertion, something like `obj["o"].(map[string]interface{})["name"]` (you might want be a bit more defensive to check the assertion though, if the data is untrusted).